# DB2 Views with Auto Increment

Tags: sql, db2, view, ibm-midrange

Is there a way to create a DB2 view that has a row ID/auto Increment ID?

Currently, I have a table created, but the data is not dynamic like a view is.

When I created the table I used `select dec(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),7,0) as numb` and then the rest of the fields are data pulled from various tables.

I need this to be a view so the data updates from the other tables, but need the `NUMB` field for when we export the view for another data load.

Comment: ...What do you plan on using this ID for?  If the underlying data changes that implies the autogen id changes too, which might cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you used

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE 
  AS (SELECT DEC(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),7,0) AS numb
      ...
     ) WITH DATA
```

Just use CREATE VIEW

```
CREATE VIEW MYVIEW 
  AS (SELECT DEC(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),7,0) AS numb
      ...
     )
```

Comment: I did use the Create table as () with data. But create view does not work when you attempt to view the view in WRKDBF and when you go to export the view with CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(FILES/MYTABLE) TOSTMF('/misc/data/mytable.txt'

Comment: Hmm...CPYTOIMPF works overs views normally, but apparently not one with ROW_NUMBER().  Consider opening a PMR with IBM

Comment: @QCTechJunkie `...does not work ... in WRKDBF and ... with CPYTOIMPF` Since WRKDBF isn't a native command (and is no longer maintained), it's irrelevant to the question. However, for CPYTOIMPF, we need to see the **actual view DDL** in order to see how it might need to be changed.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY  ` in the `OVER` clause you're pretty much _guaranteed_ that no two runs will have the same ordering, which might be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought...but I added a ORDER BY to the ROW_NUMBER()  and it still wouldn't work with CPYTOIMPF..

Answer (score 0):

With db2 you can use the rrn function for the row number.  Never cast the row number to smaller than 10,0 as unexpected results may occur.

```
create view z1 as (select rrn(x) as rownumber, x.* from mytable x )
```

Comment: Of course, the rrn isn't guaranteed to be sequential (deleted rows, maybe rows that didn't commit?), stable (reorgs), reflect an `ORDER BY` clause (...not that you can use a top-level one in a view anyways).  It's also issued per-table (or file? can't remember), which, since he's doing joins means there's either duplicates or more gaps.

Comment: And since there are multiple tables in the view, there are multiple non-unique RRN()s.

Comment: @user2338816 - yes, but normally you'd only consider one source in situations like this.  The fact that you're doing joins likely means that the base table rows are duplicated or excluded because of the other tables, not that you're using the rrn from each.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse `...joins likely means that the base table rows are duplicated...` Exactly... duplicated. I.e., not unique. The RRN() of an ORDER_HEADER would duplicate for each ORDER_LINE_ITEM. Alternatively, many examples could retrieve duplicate RRN()s of secondary tables. Any number of examples can give duplicate RRN()s whether they're from a single source or not. A base table would only give unique RRN()s for JOINs that are one-to-one. Secondary tables... who knows? Mostly, of course, it just depends on the goal.